# Simple way to concatenate BIT and NVARCHAR columns

Tags: asp.net, sql, data-binding, webforms

```
MyTable
=======
Item NVARCHAR(200)
Hidden BIT
```

---

I need to load all the items from `MyTable` in a `DropDownList` in such format: Item (Hidden)

This how my list would look like:

```
Brush
Table (Hidden)
Box (Hidden)
PC
Ball
```

N.B: I've reached in my search to this SQL entry:

```
SELECT        ID, Item + '(' + CAST(Hidden AS NVARCHAR(200)) + ')' AS Conct
FROM            Items
```

Which Returns Item(0) or Item(1)

..I can't think of a simple way to use for my purpose but I thought I'd change the Hidden column to NVARCHAR and store hidden or blank in it .. or maybe add another column that stores the word 'Hidden' for any '1' in the Hidden (BIT) column. What do you think guys ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CASE statement:

```
SELECT ID, 
       Item + (CASE Hidden WHEN 1 THEN ' (Hidden)' ELSE '' END) AS Conct
FROM Items
```

Comment: The first answer (Y) .. Perfectly Simple THANKS! =D

Answer (score 1):

You could do a CASE:

```
SELECT ID, Item + (CASE Hidden
                             WHEN 1 THEN '(Hidden)'
                             ELSE ''
                        END) AS Conct
FROM   Items
```

Adding another column for the word 'Hidden' when Hidden is 1 would be redundant.

Comment: SUPER PERFECT Thanks Tim (Y) +1